# What to do with Google Analytics for domain and subdomain which will be moved to subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, subdomain, google-tag-manager, subdirectory

I have a Wordpress site (example.com) and subdomain (sub.example.com). They have separate Wordpress dashboards and work like 2 separate websites. 2 different Google Analitycs Tracking IDs set up for them, so we have 2 different Google Analytics accounts and 2 different properties respectively. Now we redesigned both websites and want to move subdomain to a subdirectory, so it will look like this: sub.example.com --> example.com/sub, but they still have 2 separate Wordpress dashboards.

My question is, what should I do with Google Analytics? Should I put the domain GA tracking code on subdirectory website as well? As the initial idea behind making moving subdomain to subdirectory was for SEO boost and consolidation of traffic.
I also would like to start using Google Tag Manager to implement GA tag.

Would appreciate some input on this as I'm really confused Thanks!

Comment: At this point, this is rather a business decision, than a programming related question. Do you treat these as separate websites? Do you want to see the visitors in unified reports or have them separated by site?

Comment: We want to see visitors from both websites in one report to understand their journey and what pages they interact with, at the same time we want to be able to see the report only for domain traffic (without subdirectory) and only for subdirectory traffic (without domain). So, if I use one GA tracking code for both websites, I would see all traffic in one account. Then my question - how I can set up in GA  (probably in filters or views?) to see all traffic, only traffic for the domain, only traffic for subdirectory? And if it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'google analytics' separately for both the websites as header is different in both the websites.